# Error: ValueError: unknown url type: 'g'. Unable to connect to jdbc driver stored in GCS bucket by Dataflow script triggered by Cloud composer

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jar, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I am unable to connect to jdbc driver (jar file) stored in GCS bucket by Dataflow script triggered by Cloud composer. I have a composer script & a dataflow script.

**Composer script:** Triggers the Dataflow script to run. (in Dags folder in composer bucket)

**Dataflow python script:** connects to MySQL in CloudSQL to read & write data to Bigquery. MySQL Jar files: `mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar` (both are stored in bucket location of Composer bucket).

Code uses `apache_beam.io.jdbc.ReadFromJdbc` to read the MySQL table. `classpath`

**Dataflow Script:**

```
"""Cloud sql mysql to bigquery"""
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc

def run(argv=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    gcp_options = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    gcp_options.project = 'project-name'

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        jdbc_url = (
            "jdbc:mysql://someIPhere:3306/dbname"
        )
        # classpath='gs://us-central1-viknesh-compose-0000000-bucket/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar'
        # classpath=["com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.7.2"]
        # classpath=["gs://us-central1-viknesh-compose-0000000-bucket/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar"]
        classpath=["https://storage.cloud.google.com/viknesh-poc-bucket/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar"]
        query = 'SELECT * FROM Persons'
        output_table = 'project-name:datasets_us_cent1.new_test_mysql_cloudsql'

        sql_data = p | 'Read from Cloud SQL' >> ReadFromJdbc(
            query=query,
            jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
            table_name='new_test_mysql_cloudsql',
            username='root',
            password='mypassword',
            # driver_class_name='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
            driver_class_name='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
            classpath=classpath
        )

        sql_data | 'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(
            table=output_table,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

My composer dag code can trigger the dataflow code.
I am getting an error that dataflow code is unable to parse the location (gcs path). With multiple warnings & error.

Warning: (for every letter in the path) it shows the warning `WARNING:root:Unable to parse g into group:artifact:version.`

**Error:** `ValueError: unknown url type: 'g'`

**Warning:** [image: Warning for each letter in classpath]

I also checked the I/O connectors provided beam [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/). It looks like python is not a native connector & has only **via-X language** & X language has some difficulty.

I tried multiple ways in setting permissions to service account & reading maven pages, it wasn't getting resolved. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html

> classpath – A list of JARs or Java packages to include in the classpath for the expansion service. This option is usually needed for jdbc to include extra JDBC driver packages. The packages can be in these three formats: (1) A local file, (2) A URL, (3) A gradle-style identifier of a Maven package (e.g. “org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1”). By default, this argument includes a Postgres SQL JDBC driver.

Can you try `classpath=[classpath]`?

Comment: Yes it has to be URL & passed within '[]' square brackets. Did tried it & still have issues. Edited question with updated tries & commented few.